# Navigation drawer with swipe views

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, navigation-drawer, android-tabbed-activity

I'm developing a custom layout in Android, I have to implement a navigation drawer with swipe views.

I need to use the code that is generated from Android Studio by default, and implement the swipe views.

I need that in a single page is it available a navigation drawer with different menu, I can switch to the different page by menu in the menu or awfull between the pages by swiping your finger on the screen (i do not need the top menu with the tabs , i need only to move between the pages)

This is my source code, I have try to implement both solution:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {}

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.qrcode) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QRCode.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_qrcode) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QRCode.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

This is my basic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#B59154"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I don't understand how i can create a unique layout with this function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question but i will try to awnswer

You can create a `TabbedActivity` with `SwipeViews` and them add what you want. You need to be more specific with want you really want from `Navigation Drawer`.

OR

You can create a `Navigation Drawer` and add a `ViewPager` to it, so it works was you want.

I had the same problem as you so i used the first option :)

if you don't know how to add a `ViewPager` just say, i can try to help you with that :)

Comment: Sorry, i need to create a navigation drawer with SwipeViews.In a same " Activity " I need to have the navigation drawer with the contextual menu which i can consult the contestual information. Another way to change pages of the SwipeView and That of use contained in the activity. So to choose my content I can use NavigationDrawer or the SwipeView

Comment: this is my app:
http://imgur.com/EQAtK4C
I used tabbedActivity and them I added those things :D

Comment: Ok, Could you say to me how i can modify my code to obtain your result ?

Comment: I need only the integration between NavigationDrawer and SwipeView, i don't need button below action bar :) tnks

Comment: my advise is:

create a new project with tabbedactivity and them use that code in your project, i think thats the better way to do it, if you didt understand something from the code just say

Comment: I tried but I have problem with the integration of the navigation drawer layout and tabbed

Comment: I need to know the problems that you have so i can help you :(